# Why am I getting "None" value whilst web scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to develop a script that will get the mmr rating from this website. The code I am using to get this is:

```
r = requests.get(f"https://tracker.gg/valorant/profile/riot/curry%2366666/overview")
userPage = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
mmr = userPage.find('span', {'class': 'stat__value'})
print(mmr)
```

However, the issue I am getting when using this code is it just provides a None value although it seems I am using the correct information. How do I go about fixing this and getting the value I am looking for.

(For this profile the value would be 1,006 or whatever the mmr may be of the users profile when you're viewing this post)

Comment: My place code works fine.  print(mmr.text[:-2])

Comment: You should also `print(r.text)` to check if the content is an error page or some other unexpected result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print(mmr)
```

returns html element below

```
<span class="stat__value" data-v-1f4cec1e="" data-v-a2eef9ca="">1,006<sup data-v-1f4cec1e="" data-v-a2eef9ca="">RR</sup></span>
```

If you want to get **1,006**, then you can do either of these

```
print(mmr.contents[0]) # 1st item is string 1,006 and 2nd is <sup>
print(next(mmr.stripped_strings))   # strings or stripped_strings returns a generator containing strings, next() will throw out first item
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the correct class to find the element that contains the MMR value, but you get a None value instead of the expected result. It is possible that you are using the .string field to see the content, and it does return None, to solve this you can use .text which returns the value you are looking for.

```
r = requests.get(f"https://tracker.gg/valorant/profile/riot/curry%2366666/overview")
userPage = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
mmr = userPage.find('span', {'class': 'stat__value'})
print(mmr.text)
```